# How can I get the remote server's date and time at the client side in my application in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a cutoff time for user in my application so for this I dont want to take the current system time and instead I want to take the remote server machine's time in to consideration so How can i get the remote servers date and time in c#

Comment: How are you communicating with the remote server? What remote applications are you using? Does the remote server contain an application that you are developing?

Comment: Sounds like a classic XY question.  Where X is "how do I limit the demo time and defeat the user changing the clock".  You don't need a server.

Answer (score 0):

Write a request handler on your server that sends the date time. Without more details, its difficult to know how to implement that.

Comment: Do you have some sample code for that? I would really appreciate that

Comment: @Chetan - we need to know what you are doing for your application and server.

Comment: In my application I need to know the current time so that I would allow the user to do something? so the user can change the current system time , so I Want to take the servers time

Comment: What server? How is the server implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple web service that when invoked returns the timestamp (possibly using UTC or something).

```
[WebMethod]
    public string ServerDateTime()
    {
        serverDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return serverDate.ToString();
    }
```

You could be even lazier and have a standard asp.net page that has the same web method as well. Example: http://softwaredevscott.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1A9E939F7373F3B7!484.entry